# Getting Cucumber/Capybara to close and open another browser after scenarios

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

Say I have 3 Scenario Outlines and I need to run scenario 1 with Firefox, close the browser, then run scenario 2 with Chrome, close the browser, then finally run scenario 3 with Firefox.
Is there any way to close/quit the browser in Cucumber/Capybara after each scenario?

So far I have registered two drivers, one for Firefox and one for Chrome:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_firefox do |app|
  Capybara::Driver::Selenium.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Driver::Selenium.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

Then in hooks.rb, I'm using a 'custom' tag "@alternate_browser"

```
Before('@alternate_browser') do
  driver = Capybara.current_driver
  if driver == :selenium_firefox
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
  else
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_firefox
  end
end
```

Is there a way to force the browser to close after each scenario?

EDIT: I tried:

```
page.evaluate_script("window.close()")
page.execute_script("window.close()")
```

But both statements had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do.

- Stop closing the windows.
- Change to explicit browser tags (@firefox,@chrome)

I haven't tried it but this should work.

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_firefox do |app|
  Capybara::Driver::Selenium.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Driver::Selenium.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end


Before('@firefox') do
  Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_firefox
end

Before('@chrome') do
  Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
end
```

Comment: The issue I was having while testing my scenarios is that somehow cache/cookie causes the second/third... example in the scenario to fail. It only works if the browser is closed after running one example, opened again for the next example, and so on. All within the same scenario. This is why I was wondering if it's possible to force the browser to close somehow.

Comment: Did you managed to close the windows? I need to close the windows before certain scenarios.

Comment: You can do this to clear the session. "Capybara.current_session.driver.reset!" Or you could close it with javascript. But then its important to open a new window before the next scenario and select that new window. Checkout the Selenium docs for that. http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames